# Mongoid: check for existing documents/embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

is there a preferred way to check for existing documents via mongoid?

if i do `Model.find('id')'`, and the id is nil or the document doesn't exist, it throws an exception... i want it to return an empty array.

if i do `Model.where(:id => 'id')`, and the id is nil, it returns all the documents... i also want it to return an empty array.

and then with `Model.criteria(:id => 'id').to_a`, for whatever reason never returns a result, even with a valid object id.  not sure what is going on there...

but basically with activerecord i would just use the `exists?` finder method, so i am looking for the mongoid alternative.

Comment: What about Model.find('id') rescue [] ?

Comment: i suppose that is a possibility, but different exceptions are thrown depending on if the id is nil, or if an object is not found.  it also doesn't play well in my views for things like `Model.find('id') ? 'id' : 'nothing found'`.

Comment: What about Model.where(:id => id.to_s) ?

Comment: i was actually using a hardcoded string for testing... ie `Model.where(:id => '4d9ad01de1607c4bc000001a').first`.  but even using to_s, a nil id still returns all the records. `Model.where(:id => nil.to_s).first`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mongoid 2.0, Following seems to do what you want:

```
User.all.for_ids('4d9ad01de1607c4bc000001a').entries
```